# Spring Boot - check if target date is reached for objects

Tags: java, spring

I don't know if it's a real question or not... But i'd like to know how some of you will approach this...

I have a Spring Boot application.
Then I have a Interruttore.class, which has, among others this field `timeoutDate`which is a Date.

In the app, various instances of this class are used. The timeoutDate field can be updated, for every single object, by various factors. I need to know when the actual date reaches the timeutDate.

In a very simple (and not optimized) way i would have created a `@Scheduled` task, but the delay will be too short and i don't like it, how can i do?

Answer (score 1):

> In a very simple (and not optimized) way i would have created a
>   @Scheduled task, but the delay will be too short and i don't like it,
>   how can i do?

Why too short ?
You can use the delay you wish.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=50000) // 50 secs
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000) // 1 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Quartz** or **Jesque(redis)**. Whatever task needs to be executed, you can schedule that task at that time.

If this time value can be updated anytime, you can cancel(unschedule) the previously scheduled task(using task identifiers or keys) and reschedule it with the updated time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for Spring's various task scheduling APIs: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

You have plenty of choices. I think the "not optimised" idea you might have is to schedule a repeating task which searches your beans to find the expired ones. That would indeed be inefficient for large numbers of beans.

You could simply create a scheduled task *for each bean with a timeoutDate*, created at the same time as that bean, and when its timeoutdate is updated (Spring AOP could help with this).

Alternatively you could keep a list of beans, sorted by timeout date. Schedule a task for the time of the earliest expiry. It reaps that bean and any others who's time is past, then schedules a new task for the time of the next expiry.

If you do this, you need to make sure that:
 - it handles new objects added to the list (perhaps with an expiry date earlier than the currently scheduled cull)
 - it handles the case where an object is removed for a reason other than a timeout

(Unless neither of those things can happen -- in which case don't worry about it!)